# How to select all content include bullet and numbering?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, microsoft-word, html

I am using chrome, firefox and word office.

When i try one of theme to copy all content (from web or from .doc document) which have bullet or numbering, it doesn't select bullet or numbering.

http://tinyurl.com/bulletnumbering

So, when i paste it, it doesn't have.

How could i select all include bullet and numbering and paste with it?

Any idea?

Comment: If I select the text in Firefox (doesn't show the bullets/numbers as selected though) and paste it in Word I do get the bullets/numbers, but of course in Notepad I don't. Perhaps you can try Alt+left mouse to select and see if that makes a difference for you?

Comment: Sometimes the bullets or numbering are just contextual formatting and not hard coded symbols.  That's typically when you select some numbered or bulleted text and the text is highlighted but not the numbers/bullets.  In that case, there aren't actual numbers or bullets to copy.  If it's HTML, it needs to be recognized as such for the markup to be properly displayed when the selection is pasted.

Answer (score 1):

As @fixer1234 states, to capture numbering as shown on the page, you must copy the **full HTML block** behind the numbered section, including the list start and end, e.g. <o1> and </o1> in the formatted list below, and then paste it into an application that can "understand" HTML formatting, e.g. LibreOffice or MS Word.

1. Coffee
2. Tea
3. Milk

See [Numbered Lists](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllists02.htm) or [HTML Lists](http://www.w3schools.com/Html/html_lists.asp) for more information. Also, choose *View Page Source* from a right-click context menu to see how the list *actually* looks in the underlying page. Note that HTML takes care of the numbering, so that if the first item were to be removed, the list would *still start with 1.*

Comment: It's `<ol>...</ol>`, not `<o1>...<\o1>`. Also the **full HTML block** behind the numbered section, including the list start and end, need not be copied for the items to be recognised as being part of a list. For example if I select from the "ea" of "Tea" onwards till the "Mil" of "Milk", that neither includes the `<ol>` nor the `</ol>`, but still in Word "ea" and "Mil" are pasted with bullets. This is because the `</li>` after "ea" and the `<li>` before "Mil" are enough to tell Word that some sort of HTML list is involved, but since it doesn't know which kind, it defaults to an unordered list.

Comment: (contd.) For the items to be specifically recognised as being part of an *ordered* list though, yes, the `<ol>...</ol>` needs to be copied. What your answer doesn't address though is why when the OP copies and pastes "all content", he's still not seeing the bullets/numbers in Word.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the bullet points or numbers in HTML lists can be problematic because they (usually) aren't actually part of the text content of the page, but are generated by the browser from the HTML using the [`::marker` CSS pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker). I don't completely understand all of the implications of why this works but if you Select-All and Copy from within a browser and then Paste into MS Word you will indeed get all the list formatting (numbers or bullet points).

Obviously copying the entire page isn't a suitable solution; you end up copying everything and it can be quite a process getting rid of all the content you don't want.

To get ordered or unordered lists from an internet page into MS Word, I have found the following to work consistently:

1. Open the browser Developer Tools to view the HTML
2. Right-click the HTML list element - `<ol>` (ordered list) or `<ul>` (unordered list)
3. Select "Copy" > "Copy element" / "Outer HTML" or similar (it's important that the copied content includes the opening `<ol>` or `<ul>` and closing `</ol>` or `</ul>` tags).
4. Open a plain text editor, e.g. Notepad in Windows
5. Paste
6. Save with an .html file extension
7. Open newly created HTML file with a browser
8. Select-All and Copy
9. Open MS Word
10. Paste

All list numbering/bullets will be included.